# React Material UI Color Picker with Formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, color-picker

I'm trying to use [material-ui-color](https://mikbry.github.io/material-ui-color/?path=/story/docs-intro--page) picker with [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview). I'm using React Material UI `FormControl`. Here's what I've tried for the color picker:

```
 <FormControl
     variant="outlined"
     error={Boolean(touched.color_code && errors.color_code)}>
        <ColorPicker
             id="color_code"
             defaultValue="#03a9f4"
             onChange={handleChange}
             value={values.color_code}
             aria-describedby="color_code-error-text"
             name="color_code"
        />
        {touched.color_code && errors.color_code ? (
            <FormHelperText id="color_code-error-text">
                {errors.color_code}
            </FormHelperText>
            ) : null
        }
 </FormControl>
```

Now, the issue is that, the selected color code is not being populated inside `formik` form values when I'm submitting the form.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The onChange function provides the hex code directly. You can use the setFieldValue function provided from useFormik hook. So try doing the following:

```
<ColorPicker
  id="color_code"
  defaultValue="#03a9f4"
  onChange={(value) => setFieldValue("color_code", value)}
  value={values.color_code}
  aria-describedby="color_code-error-text"
  name="color_code"/>
```

I hope this helps!